# Write Excel From ArcGIS Pro, Async

Tags: excel, arcgis-pro-sdk, multithreading

I am  having trouble writing to an excel file from ArcGIS Pro Sdk add-in that I created, I have a basic understanding of multithread, I am using task but the main thread does not wait for the excel to finish before trying to move ahead.

here is the helper I created.

```c#
public class ReportHelper
{
    public ReportHelper()
    {

    }

    public async Task WriteReport(string path)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            excel.Visible = false;
            excel.DisplayAlerts = false;
            Workbook wrkbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(path).Replace(".gdb", "_importreport.xlsx");
            string sheetname = new string(filename.Take(11).ToArray());
            string directoryname = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
            string savename = Path.Combine(filename, directoryname);
            Worksheet wrksheet = (Worksheet)wrkbook.Sheets.Add(After: wrkbook.Sheets[wrkbook.Sheets.Count]);
            //MessageBox.Show(sheetName);
            wrksheet.Name = sheetname;
            int x = 1;
            List<DataRecord> dRecords = Model.FeatureRecord;
            if (dRecords == null || dRecords.Count() < 1) return;
            foreach(DataRecord drecord in dRecords)
            {
                wrksheet.Cells[x, 1] = drecord.FeatureType;
                wrksheet.Cells[x, 2] = drecord.FeatureCount;
                wrksheet.Cells[x, 3] = drecord.ImportCount;
            }
            wrkbook.SaveAs(savename, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, false, false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            wrkbook.Close();
            excel.Quit();
        });

    }
}
```

I have found async streamwriter methods but I cannot find any awaitable methods for excel.

I am just trying to call these from button clock, everything works fine until I try to write the excel.

```c#
private  void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel1.Enabled = false;

    Loader loader = new Loader();
    ReportHelper rpthelper = new ReportHelper();

    QueuedTask.Run(async () =>
    {
        await QueuedTask.Run( async () =>
        {
            foreach (string path in Model.DailyGdbs)
            {

                await loader.ReturnMasterPointList(Model.MasterGdb);

                await loader.Load(path);

                await rpthelper.WriteReport(path);
            }
        });
        await AsyncMessageBox();

    });
    //await AsyncMessageBox();
    //MessageBox.Show("The data has been loaded");
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the first `QueuedTask.Run()` be awaited? And BTW, why do you have two nested QueuedTasks, I don't really think that should be necessary. And if you're calling `WriteReport()` only from QueuedTasks, it doesn't need to be async either. Finally, I'd move the call to the MessageBox outside `QueuedTask.Run()`, since it should be on the UI thread anyway.